# how to update my textbox total price which is in listbox

Tags: visual-studio-2015, textbox, listbox

what i want to do is i added item into the listbox the textbox will auto update. This i have done i can added in the price will be add but only for quantity 1 if i add 1 item for more than 1 quantity will only be count as quantity 1 item price how to solve?

[image]

```
count = Math.Round(qty_of_item, 2) * (product_price)

        lblprice.Text = (" Rm " & count)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(product_name)

        ListBox4.Items.Add(product_class)
        ListBox5.Items.Add(product_size)

        ListBox3.Items.Add((" " & Math.Round(qty_of_item)))
        ListBox2.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(count))

        caculate = count

        total = 0

        Dim price As Decimal = 0
        price = total + caculate

        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 'get the item count inside listview
            price = (CDec(ListBox2.Items(0).ToString())) 'get the value of item of each item in each listbox row
            total += price 'add price into total
        Next

        txtsubtotal.Text = FormatCurrency(total)

        gst = total * 0.06
        txtgst.Text = FormatCurrency(gst)

        total_after_gst = total + gst
        txtfinaltotal.Text = FormatCurrency(total_after_gst)

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Qty value cant be empty And only allow Integer", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End If
```

**Updated**

this still cant fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `price` in lieu of `caculate` in the `For - Next loop`

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 'get the item count inside listview
    price = CDec(ListBox2.Items(i)) 'get the value of item of each item in each listbox row
    total += price 'add price into total
Next
```

Comment: cant and i have update my code but still didn't work

Comment: See updated answer. But should there still be issues you must be more specific: what "doesn't work"? Is any error thrown? If yes at which line and of which kind?

Comment: thx it work!!! before the issue i faced is when i added the item multiple will only + the 1st item price.